# Django Signal vs Python Threading

Tags: python, django, django-signals

Its hard to explain what I am trying to achieve. Please have the patience to go through this. And let me know if you have any questions.

Say I have a Django project with two applications which I would like to have them coupled loosely. One of the application is 'Jobs' and other is 'Notifications'.

Now I want to create notifications when the Job instance is updated. So, I was thinking of using Django Signals. But some of the reservations I have are:

1. If I use the build-in signals like post_save. I could validate the conditions on job instance and generate notification(which is good). But the problem comes when, in the same view logic I call the save method on job instance multiple times. This would generate notifications multiple times. Else, I use the home made signals I would be required to call it manually which is not good for loose coupling.
2. Moreover, the signals are not asynchronous so, I would have to wait for the notification generation to complete before I can proceed.

Can anyone please suggest a good implementation strategy using Signals. One solution I was looking into was Python Threading which seems to take care of the asynchronous problem. But are there any other consequences of using Threading.

Comment: Not specifically but I have an understanding for AMQP. But I am looking for a relatively easier solution. Due to shortage of time available.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: Also, I would need a server to maintain the broker which I am really trying to avoid

Comment: Celery's actually pretty easy to set up, and the django-celery extension can help you too. You'll need a broker, that's true, but can't really think of an easier asynchronous implementation.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: I see, I may take a look into that module but what do think about Python Threading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use django-celery with RabbitMQ. You can add the notifications thing in the tasks of celery and have your view start the task queque. Have a look....I hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Yeah I understand after doing a significant research I have found AMQP is the scalable way of going ahead. Though RabbitMQ is an overkill may be I would move on to Redis

Comment: Yeah....Redis is also very good. But there is a caution in the documentation about Redis. So test properly.